# Slow select in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm having problems with a query in mysql. For plotting a chart, I'm creating a temporary table with 'X SECOND' intervals with this simple structure:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE intervals (date DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

and querying this SELECT:

```
SELECT COUNT(dt.Device) AS count, i.date 
FROM intervals i LEFT JOIN device_tracker dt ON 
    i.date <= dt.date AND 
    i.date + INTERVAL X SECOND >= dt.date 
GROUP BY i.date
```

`Device` is primary key and dt.date is index.

with 20000 rows in the device_tracker AND 30-35 intervals query takes about 4-5 seconds. Is that normal? Can I do something to improve the speed?

This is the explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key      key_len  ref   rows    Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    SIMPLE      i       index   NULL            PRIMARY  8        NULL  29      Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE      dt      ALL     date            NULL     NULL     NULL  21594
```

**EDIT**: Last_time doesn't exists, I'm using date instead.

Comment: Do you have a index on dt.Last_Time ?

Comment: Was my fault, I changed the name of the field time ago. The problem continues with index.

Comment: Does the explain change if you move the interval calculation to the right side of the ON condition? As in i.date >= dt.date - INTERVAL X SECOND?

Comment: Another suggestion: maybe you can create the temp table with two columns: date and date+interval, called 'start' and 'end' for example. Then you won't have the calculation in the join: ON i.start <= dt.date AND i.end >= dt.date. It may be faster...

Comment: I will try both changes. The last one sounds interesting!

Comment: @Javier - let me know how it goes, I'm curious... :)

Comment: @Galz - Same result with your proposals: but changing the joint to: `SELECT count(dt.device), i.date FROM device_tracker dt LEFT JOIN intervals i ...` It takes around ONLY 0.4 seconds. The only problem is that I obtain 1 new category with i.date = NULL. If I place a WHERE to filter this category, the query starts to take about 4-5 seconds again... WEIRD!

Comment: @Javier - try using HAVING instead of where: `SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY ... HAVING i.date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Galz You are a GENIUS! Actually I still think it's something weird with sentence, or something badly configured with indexes, but for now I will use this solution. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Galz response:

try using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`: `SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY ... HAVING i.date IS NOT NULL`

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is possibly the Last_Time field in device_tracker.  You might try an index on both date and last_time...as in:

```
CREATE INDEX myGreatIdx ON device_tracker(date, Last_Time);
```

Comment: Was my fault, I changed the name of the field time ago. The problem continues with index.